# Implementing BootBox (JS library) on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, alert

I am new to both javascript and PHP, but would love to learn how to combine the two.

Here is the php code i have:

```
<?php
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
if(empty($username))
{
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==' crossorigin='anonymous'>";
    echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>";
    echo "<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>";
    echo "<script src = 'js/bootbox.js'>
        bootbox.alert('no user');
    </script>";
}    
?>
```

When I run the code the alert box does not come up. I am also sure that the if statement is running, so I think it has to do with my syntax.

Comment: remove `echo "<script src = 'js/bootbox.js'>
        bootbox.alert('no user');
    </script>" ` add as ` echo "<script src = 'js/bootbox.js'>
    </script>"`

Comment: add alert as this `echo "<script>bootbox.alert('no user');</script>"`

Comment: Modifying Azzi's comment 
remove ' echo "<script src = 'js/bootbox.js'> bootbox.alert('no user'); </script>" 
with
echo "<script src = 'js/bootbox.js'></script>";
echo "<script>bootbox.alert('no user');
    </script>";

Comment: @parag i gave it a shot however still no luck. is there any way i can go about debugging this?

Comment: @user3242614 did you get any js errors?

Comment: @parag none that I know of. Is there a more precise way to check other tan outputting alerts?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?php
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
if(empty($username))
{
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==' crossorigin='anonymous'>";
    echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>";
    echo "<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>";
    echo "<script src = 'js/bootbox.js'></script>";
   echo "<script>bootbox.alert('no user');</script>";
}
```

?>